# How to skip and retrieve all rows from up to down in MySQL after sum to some specific value?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, amazon-aurora

Let's say I have these type of data in a database table. How can I perform a query like skipping some row and passing some value it should skip some adding value rows and sum from other values rows up to down rows and select all the rows which are required to sum up the value.

expected results will be as below,

1. When I skip value 3 and pass value 11 it should skip first row and sum from second rows as second row has remaining 2 value in it from up to down rows and sum rows with id 2 3 4 i.e (3+7+10) as 11 falls in forth row range and select all rows that equals or have greater) the value.

2.Let's say if I skip 5 and pass 20 value it should sum row 3 4 5 as 1 2 row is skipped and sum from 3rd row and 20 falls in (7+10+11) column and select all 3 rows.

3.Let's say if I skip 6 and pass 20 value it should sum row 3 4 5 as 1 2 row is skipped and third row is included as 6 value falls in it and 20 falls in (7+10+11) column and select all 3 rows.

```
ID, TABLE_COLUMN
1,2
2,3
3,7
4,10
5,11
6,15
```

I have tried doing this and it works for only non skipping method. thats is no row is skipped and it sum from row 1 .

```
select id, table_column
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        @wsm := @wsm + table_colum wsm
    from (select * from mytable order by id) t
    cross join (select @wsm := 0) v
) t
where wsm >= 20 and wsm - table_column < 20
order by id
```

NOTE: MySQL version is 5.7.12. (Amazon AWS MySQL Aurora; that means I cannot upgrade the version of MySQL).

DEMO: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/obsq2xRuk8Y2hCRhdo1eHT/4 (this is for without skipping. now i need some skipping rows feature)

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want,.

Comment: @GordonLinoff expected results will be as i have pointed in 1 2 and 3 point. thanks

Comment: Completely incomprehensible.

Comment: @P.Salmon please read in point 1 2 and 3 for my desired result.

Comment: I did , several times, - what do you mean by skip value and pass value and how do you intend passing them..

Comment: You lost me at "Let's". Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: its something like LIMIT and OFFSET . skip value means i need to ignore the summing rows and pass value is summing after the ignoring rows it should sum up to down wards.

Comment: This looks like some sort of last in first out where you are interested in the most recent rows , prior to a specified row id when summed cover a specified amount.

Comment: @P.Salmon https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/obsq2xRuk8Y2hCRhdo1eHT/4